# "expected a string enum" error when attempting to add text strip

Tags: error

I use the following code to add a text strip:

```
tStripAdd = "frame_start=" + fStart + ", frame_end=" + fEnd + ", channel=" + tChan + ", type='TEXT'"
print('tStripAdd = ' + tStripAdd)
#tStripAdd = frame_start=1, frame_end=164, channel=4, type='TEXT'- result of print command
bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(tStripAdd)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add" error, expected a string enum in ('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN', 'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA', 'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN', 'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA', 'EXEC_SCREEN')
```

Any suggestion as to what the problem is? How to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You are passing a string into the function instead of the actual arguments. Since `effect_strip_add` doesn't have any function signature that takes a string as first arguments you're getting the `TypeError` exception. The concept of keyword arguments is explained in [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) of the Python docs.

The proper way of calling the function is passing each of the arguments.

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(frame_start=fStart, frame_end=fEnd, channel=tChan, type='TEXT')
```

---

[`bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151006/expected-a-string-enum-error-when-attempting-to-add-text-strip) is documented in Blender 2.8 Python API with the following function signature:

> `bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(frame_start=0, frame_end=0,
>   channel=1, replace_sel=True, overlap=False, type='ALPHA_OVER',
>   color=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))`
>
> Add an effect to the sequencer, most are applied on top of existing
>   strips
>
> Parameters:
>
> - frame_start (*int in [-inf, inf], (optional)*) – Start Frame, Start frame of the sequence strip
> - frame_end (*int in [-inf, inf], (optional)*) – End Frame, End frame for the color strip
> - channel (*int in [1, 32], (optional)*) – Channel, Channel to place this strip into
> - replace_sel (*boolean, (optional)*) – Replace Selection, Replace the current selection
> - overlap (*boolean, (optional)*) – Allow Overlap, Don’t correct overlap on new sequence strips
> - type (*enum in ['CROSS', 'ADD', 'SUBTRACT', 'ALPHA_OVER', 'ALPHA_UNDER', 'GAMMA_CROSS', 'MULTIPLY', 'OVER_DROP', 'WIPE', 'GLOW',
>     'TRANSFORM', 'COLOR', 'SPEED', 'MULTICAM', 'ADJUSTMENT',
>     'GAUSSIAN_BLUR', 'TEXT', 'COLORMIX'], (optional)*) – Type, Sequencer
>     effect type
>
>   - `CROSS` Crossfade, Crossfade effect strip type.
>   - `ADD` Add, Add effect strip type.
>   - `SUBTRACT` Subtract, Subtract effect strip type.
>   - `ALPHA_OVER` Alpha Over, Alpha Over effect strip type.
>   - `ALPHA_UNDER` Alpha Under, Alpha Under effect strip type.
>   - `GAMMA_CROSS` Gamma Cross, Gamma Cross effect strip type.
>   - `MULTIPLY` Multiply, Multiply effect strip type.
>   - `OVER_DROP` Alpha Over Drop, Alpha Over Drop effect strip type.
>   - `WIPE` Wipe, Wipe effect strip type.
>   - `GLOW` Glow, Glow effect strip type.
>   - `TRANSFORM` Transform, Transform effect strip type.
>   - `COLOR` Color, Color effect strip type.
>   - `SPEED` Speed, Color effect strip type.
>   - `MULTICAM` Multicam Selector.
>   - `ADJUSTMENT` Adjustment Layer.
>   - `GAUSSIAN_BLUR` Gaussian Blur.
>   - `TEXT` Text.
>   - `COLORMIX` Color Mix.
> - color (*float array of 3 items in [0, 1], (optional)*) – Color, Initialize the strip with this color (only used when type=’COLOR’)

Comment: Thank you. Tat's one more problem solved. On to the next.

Comment: On second thought, no. It does not work. I do get a different error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/proj005/proj005.py", line 137, in <module>
    bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add(frame_start=fStart, frame_end=fEnd, channel=tChan, type='TEXT')
  File "/home/ec2-user/blender280/2.80/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.sequencer.effect_strip_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: @mcgeo52 It is correct. You are not in the right context to execute the operator though.

Comment: This does work:
eff = sequences.new_effect(
            name=tField,
            type="TEXT",
            channel=tChan,
            frame_start=fStart,
            frame_end=fEnd)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    eff = sequences.new_effect(
        name=tField,
        type="TEXT",
        channel=tChan,
        frame_start=fStart,
        frame_end=fEnd)
```